Shadow weight enumerators
Is there any physical intuition or motivation behind the "shadow weight enumerator" of a quantum error correcting code? (Reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9611001 and https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2024/cmsc858G/)

can you add a reference to what you are referring to?
